# How to do a touchscreen calibration with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml, embedded-linux

For my current QML project I have to provide a Touchscreen-Calibration Utility. I'm working with an embedded Linux device that has the `tslib` installed. The latter can be used to calibrate the touchscreen.

I'd like now to implement a touch-calibration-mode into my QML Application.

I figured out that I need to modify the `/etc/pointercal` file within my embedded Linux but I have no idea how to generate/calculate this values with my Qt/QML-Application.

Here's my `/etc/pointercal` file:

```
-282 -55301 54593224 -35954 193 33707528 65536 800 480
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Here's how I did it.

**Add the tslib to the *.pro-file**

```
LIBS += -L/PATH_TO_SDK_FILESYSTEMROOT/usr/lib/ -lts
INCLUDEPATH += /PATH_TO_SDK_FILESYSTEMROOT/usr/lib
DEPENDPATH += /PATH_TO_SDK_FILESYSTEMROOT/usr/lib
```

**Include the header-file of the tslib into your class**

```
#include "tslib.h" /* Linux-Library to calibrate the Touch-Screen */
```

**Finally you should be able to use the tslib**

The rest is pretty easy, you should have a look on the example on git `ts_calibrate.c`

https://github.com/kergoth/tslib/tree/master/tests